# How do I copy an import spec from excel to access?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have an import specification already mapped out in MS Excel.

When I try to copy and paste this into the "Advanced Text File Import" wizard in MS Access, however, it will validate the input with no error only to provide one when I get to the last step.

Has anyone encountered this problem, and do they have a fix for it?  I could manually enter the spec, but this would be very time consuming as there are 200+ fields.

Thanks.

Comment: Might be a lot easier to create a schema.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

highlight the top corner of the import routine table and paste (Cont V) 
the table must be in the same format, so best way would be to copy an existing import spec by highlighting the the import spec (top left hand corner of spec table) and cntl C and paste into excel, adjust to your new spec and paste back in, highlight the top corner of the import routine table and paste (Cont V)

I have found this out today after years of thinking the import spec side of access is a ridiculous.

Comment: I completely forgot about this question after finding a solution.  You can in fact copy from an Excel sheet to the Access Data Sheet view in the Layout Spec wizard.  The only advice I would provide other developers is to ensure that your field names are completely unique.  I have also had to change white space to underscores to get the import to validate correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, you are not able to copy a specification from one database to another.  If Access-Access transfers of Import/Export specifications are prohibited, then it makes sense that Excel-Access transfers are also unavailable.

However, the specifications are stored in MS Access in tables, specifically MSysImexSpecs and MSysImexColumns tables.  Depending on what version you use for MS Access, the way you view these hidden tables is different.  Google can quickly guide you to them.

Some VBA Coding can achieve Access-Access transfer of the specifications by reading the contents of MSysImexSpecs in the source database, and inserting the data into MSysImexSpecs in the destination table.

Because Excel doesn't utilize tables, I honestly don't believe that there is a solution faster than rebuilding the specification in MS Access.

Below is a code example for Access-Access migration of Import/Export Specifications I found today.  If you know how the ImEx Specs are stored in Excel (possibly in a collection?) then the below code may be altered to migrate from the Excel collection to Access tables.

```
Sub GetSpecs()
Dim accApp As Object
Dim SourceDBName As String
Dim DbPath As String
Dim CurrDB As String

SourceDBName = "C:\SourceDB.mdb"
DbPath = "C:\TargetDBPath\"  'Make sure about last slash

Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
CurrDB = Dir(DbPath & "*.mdb", vbNormal)
Do Until Len(CurrDB) = 0
    If Not DbPath & CurrDB = SourceDBName Then
        accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase DbPath & CurrDB
        On Error GoTo errhandler
        accApp.CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete "MSysIMEXSpecs"
        accApp.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", SourceDBName, acTable, "MSysIMEXSpecs", "MSysIMEXSpecs"
        accApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
        CurrDB = Dir()
    End If
Loop
accApp.Quit
MsgBox "Done", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Error"
Exit Sub

errhandler:
If Err = 3265 Then
    Resume Next
Else
    MsgBox Err & " - " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
    If Not accApp Is Nothing Then accApp.Quit
End If
End Sub
```

Source:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?58094-Import-Specifications